# Delete Gridview row fires on each page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, delete-row

I have a gridview that deletes data from xml file when delete button on row is clicked. The problem is after I delete a row and refresh the page the rows below are automatically deleted on each page refresh even though their delete row button is not clicked 
I don't know how to solve this 
this is my delete function:

```
BindGridView();
DataSet dsGrid = (DataSet)BankGrid.DataSource;
dsGrid.Tables[0].Rows[BankGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex].Delete();
dsGrid.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
BindGridView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delete code should be sitting in the grid view row deleting event

```
   DataSet dsGrid =  banksDataSet.ReadXml(filePath); //global variable
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

 dsGrid.Tables[0].Rows[BankGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex].Delete();
 dsGrid.AcceptChanges();
 dsGrid.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
 BindGridView();

}
  protected void BindGridView()
           {
       GridView1.Datasource=dsGrid;
       Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
```

And in your page load

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      BindGridView()
    }

    }
```

Comment: DataSet dsGrid = (DataSet)BankGrid.DataSource; is not working

Comment: How are you populating your your data source?

Comment: this is the delete function  protected void BtnDelete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {        
                int index = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                BindGridView();
                DataSet dsGrid = (DataSet)BankGrid.DataSource;
                dsGrid.Tables[0].Rows[BankGrid.Rows[index].DataItemIndex].Delete();
                dsGrid.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
                BindGridView();
        
    }

Comment: and this is pageload   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {

            DataSet banksDataSet;
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml");
            banksDataSet = new DataSet();
            //Read the contents of the XML file into the DataSet
            banksDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
            
            BankGrid.DataSource = banksDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            BankGrid.DataBind();
        }

      
    }

Comment: When you  load your dataset you don't have have to cast it.See my updated answer.